# Convention of @@

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the convention behind the double at (`@@`) in method declarations?

For example from: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

> Whenever an object needs to be iterated (such as at the beginning of a
>   for..of loop), its @@iterator method is called with no arguments, and
>   the returned iterator is used to obtain the values to be iterated.

Comment: I imagine it's because...it's extremely unlikely for somebody to already have `@@` so it makes it look "special".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a specification shorthand for "[well-known symbols](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-well-known-symbols)," rather than something you'd type literally. For instance, `@@iterator` is `Symbol.iterator`, which is the key you'd use to get the default [iterator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-iterator-interface) for an object:

```
let defaultIterator = theObject[Symbol.iterator];
```